# windows cmd: read COM-port output to FINDSTR for output filtering

Tags: cmd, serial-port, pipe, findstr

I'm trying to display filtered data that I'm reading from COM.

I'm displaying the information as:

`COPY COM6 CON`

and this works fine for displaying ALL data.

But I want to display ONLY the data starting with "Date" and "Refractive"
This is what I'd come up with, but this doesn't word:

`ECHO COM6 | findstr /R "^Date.* ^Refractive.*" | CON`

Is there a way this CAN work?

#1~~~~~~~~~~~~~

addendum

In case you're curious how this works, or for development-purposes, I'm using this to create virtual COM-ports, linked with a null-modem cable:
The homepage for com0com project is http://com0com.sourceforge.net/.

It creates 2 COM-ports, e.g. COM5 & COM6, as if they're directly wired to eachother. So message sent to COM5 will be received by COM6 and the other way around.
So by opening 2 command-prompts, in one I read a txt-file and send it to COM5, the other listens to COM6

`cmd1: type D:\test.txt > COM5`

`cmd2: TYPE COM8 CON | findstr /R "^Date.* ^Refractive.*"`

Voila

#2~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This works too, probably a better way to write it.
Thanks @Stephan

`TYPE COM6 | findstr /R "^Date.* ^Refractive.*" > CON`

Comment: Cannot try as well, but another thing you could try is `type COM6 | findstr ...`.

Comment: This works!
By replacing ECHO with TYPE I can send it through pipe to findstr:

```TYPE COM8 CON | findstr /R "^Date.* ^Refractive.*"```

Comment: @Asgair: remove the `CON`. `TYPE COM8 CON` tries to first type `COM8` and when finished, continues to type `CON` (you probably don't want that)